# Migrate from SVN to a Git repository, where a migration of a part of the same project already took place

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

### Scenario

I am facing a situation where a project `X` which is versioned via SVN needs to be transferred to a repository `A` versioned via git.

However something similar was done with `X` before. Let project `X` consist of a working tree of three folders: `_0`, `_1`, `_2`. Years ago, a subfolder of `_0` was used to create a new git repository via `svn2git`. Folders `_1` and `_2` with all their subfolders and contents were in SVN, as they contained a lot of data that wasn't needed to maintain `X` in `A`.

However now there is a subfolder of `_2` which also needs to be in git repository `A`. It is still stored in the SVN repository and since the initial migration there have been changes by additional commits.

I am looking into `svn2git` in order to migrate a subfolder of `_2` into `A` as well, where `X` already exists. My concern is, if `_2` is transferred to a git repository via `git2svn` and then this git repository is migrated into `A`, then there is likely to be redundant history. Both `_0` and _ 2`share a commit history, the history of`_0`was originally transferred into git, the history of`_2` would now be transferred into git, but there is no mapping between these two histories, therefore I expect redundancies.

### Question

Can this task be achieved at all? Otherwise I am likely to discontinue these efforts of preserving the history of `_2` and just do a clean initial commit.

Currently I see no way to do this without expecting redundant history.

Comment: One question popped into my head: after you ran svn2git, do you get to keep a plain old `git-svn` set up that you keep un syncing? Or it's using other tricks that you sync up with svn?

Comment: No, I am doing a one time migration. There is no intent of using git to mirror and control the SVN repo, i.e. to "sync". Hope that answers your question

Comment: Yeah, it does. So no git-svn setup. Thanks! My answer remains there then. Let's see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can try is clone the branch that you need now, starting on the last revision that is present on the git repo (I don't know how that could work with svn2git. I know that plain old `git-svn` supports starting to clone at a randome revision). Then, when you have cloned that branch, you could rebase that branch on top of the original git clone (on the exact equivalent of the revision where we said to start). That could be done by adding a remote to the **new** git clone so that it can get access to the old git clone. Then rebase the branch, and then feel free to push into a branch of the first git clone.

Comment: I will have to think about this solution. Will get back to this thread mid next week. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Still not sure I understand you correctly. "clone the branch that you need now", I need now the trunk of a SVN repository, it's the same branch as was the original source for the currently existing git repo. "starting on the last revision that is present on the git repo" - this I don't understand at all. Do you mean the new git repo cloned from the SVN trunk? Or the already existing repo? I am not a 100% certain we are on the same page.

Comment: suppose that you have the svn trunk cloned in the original repo up to revision X. When creating this second clone I am talking about, you can tell `git-svn` to clone starting on revision X (with `-r X:HEAD`, if I recall correctly).